Unable to read in contents of hidden file (.file)
(My question relates to and is answered by the question Shell script read missing last line). Due to the fact that people may not know that their issue is that the file they are attempting to read in has no new line at the end, the wording of this post may help others come to that same question linked.
I'm writing a bash script that reads the contents of a hidden file, pertaining particularly to zscaler. This script is checking for the contents of a certain line in the .config.ini file inside the zscaler folder. After some debugging using print statements I realize that it seems the code isn't reading in the file at all. The script can see/find the file with a simple file check but when it comes to reading the file using BASH's read functionality, nothing echo's out with my logic. Below is my code.
#!/bin/bash
result=""
path="/Applications/Zscaler"
configfile="/Applications/Zscaler/.config.ini"
if [ -d $path ]
  then
    if [ -f "/Applications/Zscaler/.config.ini" ]
      then
        while IFS= read -r line; do
          echo "inside the while loop"
          echo "$line"
          if [[ "$line" =~ "regex check here" ]]
            then
              result="True"
            else
              result="False"
          fi
        done < $configfile
      else
        result="False"
    fi
  else
    result="Zscaler not installed"
fi
echo "<result>$result</result>"

I've thought of a possible work around which is to cat the contents of a file into a variable then parse through it that way as I've confirmed the cat command does successfully output the contents to a variable. I'm just curious as to why this isn't working. It's almost as if the hidden file is hidden to the script itself, but only when trying to use the read function; running a cat on the file correctly outputs the contents. The script is run as sudo so none of these files should be off limits to the script itself. In addition, I've run this script substituting an arbitrary text file that I created simply for testing, and this script reads in the contents fine and echo's each line. ***edit The issue never had anything to do with the file being a hidden .file.

can you just like if grep -q "regex" "$configfile" ; then result=true; else result=false; fi?

That's similiar to how I originally wrote the script. However, I need to make the script more robust and go line by line because a check like that won't see that the line is possibly commented out. I want to make sure a) the line isn't commented out and b) the line contains the contents I desire. But mainly I just want to know why the file isn't being read. An answer to this may help with other similar situations. I know I didn't put those details in the original post but they're unimportant as I'm really just trying to find out why I can't read in a hidden file.

What's the output?

What if you set -x

There is no error output, just the final output of the script with blank xml tags
. I've also put echo statements after the check to see if the file is there and the echo successfully prints. Nothing prints within the while loop. Responding to your second comment, I'm not sure what that set -x does. What would that do and where in my code would it go? Thanks

check like that won't see that the line is possibly commented ou soo like file_without_comments=$(sed '/#.*/d' "$configfile"); if grep "regex" <<<"$file_without_comments"? Bottom line, if you it "roboust", don't do half-solutions like bash, use an .ini parser, like python configparser or similar. Your script "looks" fine. Run it with set -x and check the output. I Would guess that the regex just doesn't match.

Unix doesn't really have hidden files. Files whose name begin with . aren't listed by ls by default, but otherwise they're perfectly ordinary.

@KamilCuk I appreciate your help but my main question is why aren't the contents of the hidden file read by the script.

@Barmar there absolutely are hidden files on linux and unix.

@KamilCuk the regex works and matches fine when done with the cat command. The problem, according to my debugging is it's not going into the while loop. Also, suggesting I don't use half-solutions like bash is not a solution. You don't know what my specific environment circumstances are or any stipulation with the company I work for.

A sample .config.ini would likely help, the only way in your script to get an empty result that I can see is for read -r line to return non-zero on the first call which would imply it never found a newline character inside the file.

Or if you don't want to provide a sample, try while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

@tjm3772 There is one long line in the file:
hideAppUIOnLaunch=1&deviceToken=&wait=false&token=&username=&password=&externalRedirect=false&strictEnforcement=0&userDomain=&fips=1&plugins=0&geolocation=1&externalDeviceId=&revertzcc=0&exportLogs=0&MAapiEncPubKey=
I removed the part of the config line that contains specifics to my company that I'm searching for. I added a new line to the end of the file. Is there something I can specify with the IFS to properly read the file? Not sure if that makes sense

"One long line" sounds like a perfect candidate to not be terminated by a newline.

@tjm3772 Yes this was the issue. There is a work around check in that thread:
while read line || [ -n "$line" ]; do echo $line; done < y
Thank you for your help

Also see the My text files are broken! They lack their final newlines! section of BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?).

Logical error: The result depends only from the last line.

The issue was the config file not containing a new line at the end of the file. A solution to this was posted on Shell script read missing last line
